# Which is the best cryptographic algorithm to secure MAVLink protocol?

Tags: algorithm, cryptography, dronekit, mavlink

I'm new in MAVLink. Now, I'm trying to check data loss between drone and GCS. After that I want to use one of the cryptographic algorithms to secure MAVLink protocol. Which one is the best?

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 1):

This question is pretty off-topic but since it's something I've touched before:

- You can look at the [sMavLink protocol](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mavlink/Aa51YB0FylE) and implementation I made for smaccmpilot.org.
- You can look at the successor to Secure MavLink, ["GEC"](https://github.com/GaloisInc/gec), which has both an implementation and design docs I made for smaccm.
- You can look at the authentication-only solution proposed (implemented?) by the maintainers of mavlink.  I don't really know much about that one other than it was in the works at one point.